# Including private methods but no private member variables in Javadoc

Tags: java, javadoc

Is it possible to include private methods of a class in Javadoc without all the private member variables? I'm currently using the -private option, but the private member variables are listed in the HTML although I didn't write any Javadoc for them.

Comment: Why do you want to include JavaDoc for private methods? They are designed to be private in that class and should not be of any interest outside that class.

Comment: There is an JavaDoc argument `-private` to include private methods and members. I don't know whether it is possible to distinguish between methods and members.

Comment: The documentation is part of a class project and the tutors want a complete description of all methods in Javadoc format. But if it's not possible to distinguish between methods and member variables, I will have to stick with the -private argument. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a custom doclet and tag your private fields to be excluded from generation.

refered Site: [javadoc FAQ#exclude](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/faq/index.html#exclude)

found the hint here: [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120455/how-do-i-exclude-a-specific-method-constructor-from-the-results-of-the-javadoc-a)