# How do I hide main() from Javadoc documentation?

Tags: java, javadoc

Every single Java class I write has a main() method for me to run command-line tests. However, I don't want main() to show up in generated Javadoc documentation (which I produce from running javadoc at the command-line). Does anyone know how I can have the main() method omitted from the Javadocs?

Comment: You should look into Junit.  It would eliminate the need for the main method all together.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120455/how-do-i-exclude-a-specific-method-constructor-from-the-results-of-the-javadoc-a

Comment: @kmb385: I shouldn't have to use JUnit as a solution for omitting main() from javadocs.

Comment: I agree with what kmb385 wrote.  More generally, your test code should not be in your production class.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 I would argue that your question is addressing the symptom and not the root cause.

Comment: "I'm having a problem with my garage door," I said. "You should buy a mansion that doesn't have a garage," they said.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's still no way to prevent parsing/inclusion of particular public members (like `main`).

See [this FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#exclude): an `@exclude` directove was being considered at one point.

Answer (score 1):

The [official javadoc FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#exclude) says:

> There is currently no Javadoc option to hide, exclude or suppress public members from the javadoc-generated documentation.

But several indirect options are given...

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Foo
{
    static class Main
    {
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("main");
        }
    }
}
```

oddly, though `Foo&Main` isn't public, cmd line `java` doesn't seem to mind