# Is it possible to omit the "Constant Field Values" page when generating Javadoc?

Tags: java, javadoc

Is there a way to omit the "Constant Field Values" page when generating javadocs?

Javadoc does seem to have various flags to deliberately omit various pages/links:

```
-nodeprecatedlist                 Do not generate deprecated list
-notree                           Do not generate class hierarchy
-noindex                          Do not generate index
-nohelp                           Do not generate help link
-nonavbar                         Do not generate navigation bar
```

There's a "Constant Field Values" page though, which I would like to omit, because the page is completely empty anyway. Oddly enough, "Serialized Form" has been omitted without us having to tell it to, so I don't know what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is still no simple way to do that ... see [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222387/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12222387/how-do-i-hide-main-from-javadoc-documentation) and [http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation ...](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#exclude) for more information.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Not quite the same thing. That's about hiding classes, fields, methods and the like.