# JavaDoc documentation configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, documentation

my question is next: I create documentation for my project in Intellij IDEA. I comment my code like this:

```
 /**
     *Bla bla bla bla
     *
     * @throws Exception
     */
```

But I don't want to comment getters and setters, however in my doc file i see just methods without description. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLOpx.png)

[image]

Is that normal for java documentation?

Comment: Well, what did you expect to see?

Comment: I hope there are possibility to delete getters and setters from documentation

Comment: I just happened to be looking at the Javadoc for [URI](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/net/URI.html) recently.  The class is mostly getters, and each one is documented with its own Javadoc entry.

Comment: it's just like a duplicate question with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120455/how-do-i-exclude-a-specific-method-constructor-from-the-results-of-the-javadoc-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In IntelliJ, you can go to Settings -> Editor -> Inspections and in that menu go to Javadoc -> Declaration has Javadoc problems.

In the right sidebar, on the options, scroll down and check "Ignore simple property accessors", as you can see in below image:

[image]